# Outlook.MailItem.Sender is null- to fetch From email address

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I am trying to create Outlook Addin using C#. Customizing `Application_ItemSend` event of the `Send` button.

I am unable to get from/sender email address. I am getting following things as null:

- `Outlook.MailItem.SenderEmailType`
- `Outlook.MailItem.Sender` (as this is null not able to get PrimarySmtpAddress)
- `Outlook.MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`

Any pointers what is wrong? Is it my outlook account is incorrectly configured?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code to fetch address which i am using:

```
 private string GetSenderSMTPAddress(Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {
        string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =   @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
        if (mail == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (mail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry sender =
                mail.Sender;
            if (sender != null)
            {
                //Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
                if (sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                    Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                    olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                    || sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                    Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                    olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
                {
                    //Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
                    Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser =
                        sender.GetExchangeUser();
                    if (exchUser != null)
                    {
                        return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                        PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about adding in the actual code you are using?

Comment: The code i have referred from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Sender related properties are only set after the message is actually sent. Try to use the I`tems.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder (retrieved using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`).

If `SendUsingAccount` property is not set, you can assume the default account is being used - use the first account from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection and retrieve the `Account.SmtpAddress` property.

Comment: Hi...please correct me if wrong... are you trying to say that i iterate through accounts and get first one like "Outlook.Accounts accounts = mail.GetInspector.Session.Accounts;"...but this wont work in case of multiple accounts added in outlook...is this what you are trying to say on second point..?

Comment: If SendUsingAccount is not null, you need to use data from that account. If it is null, you must assume the default account is being used. There is nothing to iterate through - the very first account in the Namespace.Accounts is the default account.

Comment: I have used this `ItemAdd` method for a while until I noticed that if an account is configured on multiple computers (each having an Outlook client), then the `ItemAdd` event is triggered on every Outlook instance for this account which is problematic...I need to react to this sent event only once...any workaround as `ItemSend` doesn't have all the informations needed (no conversationId, no entryId, no Sender, etc...) ?

Comment: You can save the computer name in a user property in the `ItemSend` event (it only fires on one computer) and then check it is value in `Items.ItemAdd` - if it does not match the name of the current machine, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38d7b25a-8762-40c6-9e0a-903549462c0b/outlookmailitemsendername-always-null-under-outlook-2007-wvsto?forum=vsto

Short answer: those items aren't populated until it's actually sent (this hook is when you are just about to send the command to the exchange server to send the email).  Use the "SendUsingAccount" field instead, as it will have all that information (in addition to the information you can find in the user's mailbox/account objects).

I'm pretty sure the reason why is that those field are not filled in until dynamic rules and policies are applied server-side.

Comment: Hi..Tried getting "SendUsingAccount", but no luck...getting "SendUsingAccount" as null. Below is the code           private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            
  Application.ItemSend += new
        Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
        }

void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(mail.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress);

}

Comment: That's why you have to use that field in addition to the information about mailbox and the current user's account (both of which you have access to).

Answer (score 0):

go for

```
 MailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
```